# How to get only create logs of Virtual Machine in Azure?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-virtual-machine, azure-monitoring

So, I can see **create_or_update** logs of my VM on activity logs. There is no filter just to get the create logs as much as I am aware.

So is there any way where I can just see the create logs of a VM using API or commands?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to achieve your requirement

1. You need to enable diagnostic settings to activity logs.
   refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log#send-to-log-analytics-workspace for enabling the diagnostic settings.
2. Once the Log analytics workspace is established, you can query the logs as

> AzureActivity
> | where OperationName == 'Create or Update Virtual Machine' and ActivitySubstatusValue == 'Created'
> | order by TimeGenerated desc

3. above output will show only the Create operations. You can further filter it based on your requirement.